# Incorrect types for Jest test.each

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

So I'm using [**`Jest#test.each`**](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#testeachtablename-fn-timeout) to run some unit tests.

Here's the actual code:

```
const invalidTestCases = [
  [null, TypeError],
  [undefined, TypeError],
  [false, TypeError],
  [true, TypeError],
];

describe('normalizeNames', () => {
  describe('invalid', () => {
    test.each(invalidTestCases)('some description for (%p, %p)', (actual, expected) => {
      expect(() => normalizeNames(actual as any)).toThrowError(expected);
    });
  });

  describe('valid', () => {
    // ...
  });
});
```

The problem is that I'm unable to run this due to typescript errors:

```
Argument of type '(actual: boolean | TypeErrorConstructor | null | undefined, expected: boolean | TypeErrorConstructor | null | undefined) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(...args: (TypeErrorConstructor | null)[] | (TypeErrorConstructor | undefined)[] | (boolean | TypeErrorConstructor)[]) => any'.
      Types of parameters 'actual' and 'args' are incompatible.
        Type '(TypeErrorConstructor | null)[] | (TypeErrorConstructor | undefined)[] | (boolean | TypeErrorConstructor)[]' is not assignable to type '[boolean | TypeErrorConstructor | null | undefined, boolean | TypeErrorConstructor | null | undefined]'.
          Type '(TypeErrorConstructor | null)[]' is missing the following properties from type '[boolean | TypeErrorConstructor | null | undefined, boolean | TypeErrorConstructor | null | undefined]': 0, 1
           test.each(invalidTestCases)('some description for (%p, %p)', (actual, expected) => {
                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

---

I also tried to use an `array` of `objects` instead of 2d `array`, like this:

```
const invalidTestCases = [
  { actual: null, expected: TypeError },
  { actual: undefined, expected: TypeError },
  { actual: false, expected: TypeError },
  { actual: true, expected: TypeError },
];

describe('normalizeNames', () => {
  describe('invalid', () => {
    test.each(invalidTestCases)('some description for (%p, %p)', ({ actual, expected }) => {
      expect(() => normalizeNames(actual as any)).toThrowError(expected);
    });
  });

  describe('valid', () => {
    // ...
  });
});
```

...but doing this way, I can't get correct test description for `object` values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm currently not somewhere I can test it, but adding type annotations usually fixes that error.

So maybe try:

```js
type testCaseErrorTypes = null|undefined|boolean
const invalidTestCases: [testCaseErrorTypes, typeof TypeError][] = [
  [null, TypeError],
  [undefined, TypeError],
  [false, TypeError],
  [true, TypeError],
];
test.each(invalidTestCases)('some description for (%p, %p)', (actual, expected) => { … }
```

This should transform `invalidTestCases` from a `(testCaseErrorTypes|TypeError)[][]` into the correct type `[testCaseErrorTypes, TypeError][]`.

Comment: `TypeError` doesn't satisfy typescript types, but `typeof TypeError` does. Also, you don't need to type the callback parameters too as they're automatically inferred.

Comment: @developer033 right, my bad. But does this fix your problem? (once your fixes to it are applied, of course)

Comment: @SourceOverflow I'm the OP :)

Comment: But both of your solutions worked for me... thanks!

Comment: oh right, apparently I can't read ^^ Glad it worked, though. I'll update the answer with @developer033's changes

Answer (score 1):

Since all the `expected` values are equal, you can just use 1d array and pass `TypeError` directly to the `toThrowError`. It would be something like this:

```
const invalidTestCases = [
  null,
  undefined,
  false,
  true,
];

describe('normalizeNames', () => {
  describe('invalid', () => {
    test.each(invalidTestCases)('some description for (%p)', actual => {
      expect(() => normalizeNames(actual as any)).toThrowError(TypeError);
    });
  });

  describe('valid', () => {
    // ...
  });
});
```